# How to Export/Import Site's structure in Liferay 6.2.x

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am looking solution to export/import site structures in Liferay 6.2.x.

Currently, Liferay supports the export/import of organization, roles, and user groups structures.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by site structure ?

Comment: Site structure - no of sites without any page/webcontent data in it. It is actually just to copy purely liferay structure only from one environment to another.

Answer (score 3):

Liferay does allow Export/Import of Site pages as .lar file.

Control Panel -> Sites -> Click on the site that you want to export.

Please select Pages -> Site Pages in left side.
You will see that public pages tab get selected in right side. Make sure you select the first item, "Page Pages" in the pages hierarchy.

There should be a link "Export" [image]

Please click on Export and select the option "Choose Content" if you do not want the data to be exported.
You can click on "Change" for Date Range and select in such a way that no data required to be included. Export as .lar file and then import to the target server, which again should be of same liferay version as source.

Another great option to use is Remote Publishing. This link provides some details for you.
http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/web/swerlen/blog/-/blogs/liferay-remote-publishing-troubleshooting

Comment: hi Haris, I am looking for Control Panel -> Sites export/import and site pages export/import. Imagine site pages lar file is exported but how it will be imported if destination liferay setup doesn't have site itself. So, instead of creating it manually I am looking for export/import option. So any idea about it?

Comment: You need to create the site manually before importing the lar file, there's no option from the panel to import a lar file that does not require the site to be created first.